# Java Streams Terminology - Difference between intermediate - non terminal

Tags: java, java-stream

When I am reading tutorials on Java Stream API (Java Platform SE 8) I see some mentions like terminal operations and non-terminal operations.

Is the term "non-terminal operations" same thing as the "intermediate operations"?

Comment: Yes.   That is correct.

Comment: @Michael did you find out that there is no such thing as "starting" operations? Why did you remove the answer?

Comment: @AndrewTobilko Wasn't really happy with it... Because these operations are defined as operations *upon* a stream, and those are not operations upon a stream.

Comment: @AndrewTobilko I think I've revised it to what I believe to be more accurate but I'm still not sure.

Comment: While it's good to know the _exact_ meaning of a given terminology. generally "non-terminal operations" is the *same thing* as "intermediate operations" or basically _any operation that's not a terminal operation_. personally, IMO There's no need to get too technical about the given terminology.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

'Non-terminal' is not really defined but I might use it to cover both 'intermediate' operations and 'source' expressions such as

```
Stream.of("foo")
```

While 'intermediate' is referring to neither the start nor the terminal operations, e.g.

```
.peak(() -> {/*...*/})
```

Comment: *"Stream operations are divided into intermediate (Stream-producing) operations and terminal (value- or side-effect-producing) operations."* ([jdk 13](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html)). They are implying that intermediate operations include "starting" ones since they both are "Stream-producing". I am not sure either.

Comment: The [streams tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/index.html#pipelines) uses the term _source_ rather than start.

Comment: @AndrewTobilko It depends in which context you're talking. 'Terminal operation' is well-defined, so 'non-terminal' is technically anything that *isn't that*. `System.out.println()` is not a "terminal operation", so could conceivably be a "non-terminal operation" (work with me for a second...). If you are talking about operations which can be performed **upon** a stream, then 'intermediate' and 'non-terminal' are the same thing but I don't think it's unreasonable (like my prev example) to lump in the creation of the stream. That's how I'd use it anyway, regardless of what's technically correct

Comment: Cheers @jaco0646

Comment: @jaco0646 that’s no contradiction. In the tutorial, the collection `roster` is the *source*, whereas the `stream()` method invoked on it can be seen as the first stream-producing, hence intermediate operation. That matches the usual meaning of the words, i.e. a source is a thing, not an operation.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I gather from the [streams tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/index.html#pipelines).

1. A **source** is a method on an object that returns a stream.
2. An **intermediate operation** is a method on a stream that returns another stream.
3. A **terminal operation** is a method on a stream that returns an object (or void).

The combination of all three (*source*, *intermediate*, and *terminal*) constitutes a **pipeline**.

Finally, all methods on a stream are collectively referred to as **aggregate operations**; so *intermediate* and *terminal* operations are both *aggregate* operations.

---

The phrase "non-terminal operation" doesn't appear in Oracle documentation; so technically it means whatever the author of an [article](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-functional-programming/streams.html#non-terminal-operations) wants it to mean. In practice, that will likely be the same as intermediate operation.

Comment: Good to have these terms defined, but what is 'non-terminal' then? Source + intermediate?

Comment: [Stream operations and pipelines](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#StreamOps) goes deeper into terminology than the tutorial mentioned above; but again doesn't specifically mention non-terminal operations.